# HP dv4-1225dx HDD problem

Tags: hard-drive, cooling, hp-pavilion

i have an hp dv4-1225dx and recently i have noticed that the hdd is getting really hot. it ranges between 55 and 70 degrees centegrade
every once in a while, i hear a click noise ( at the lower temps) and i have run the self est and it didnt detect anything
i know something is wrong but what
smart data from programs says that the airflow temp is critical and can cause fail
any clues?

Answer (score 0):

The cooler a drive runs, the longer it will last.

You might see if you can add an extra case fan to that PC. They also make hard drive coolers that attach to the drive itself, but there would need to be room in the hard drive bay to accommodate it.

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=hard+drive+cooler&aq=f&aqi=g3g-m1g-ms1g-m5&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=CyjISmWUqTI-YAZzGhgTm65iFCwAAAKoEBU_QJI_1

.

Comment: its a laptop and its raised up
i noticed that the lower temps i hear clicking

Answer (score 0):

The click noise may be the HDD powering itself off (particularly if the computer has been idle for more than a few mins). You can check this setting in the Power Management part of control panel (may have to look at advanced settings).

Repetitive faint clicking is normally just the drive seeking to read data and isnt anything to worry about.

How often is "every once in a while" that the temps get to 55-70? HDD temp depends on how much work the HDD is doing, as well as other components like CPU and graphics (heat transfers easily in a laptop), and the ambient temperature (eg its higher if its sitting on your lap compared to a desk).

Check Task Manager and see if CPU usage is high/maxed out, or if you have antivirus or other HDD intensive tool, check its not doing a scan or something. If you are still getting high temps even with no HDD intensive tasks running, you could try giving the cooling fan and vents a blast with compressed air, they may be clogged with dust. Check the CPU temperature as well with an app like [CoreTemp](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it has already been solved. It was not the hdd at all. It was the cooling fan. Shortly after i posted this, the noise stopped and so did the fan. The computer would not stay on for mare than 5 min after that due to over heating. I am eventually going to order a new part to replace it but it shall be a pain since its a laptop.